# speeding up MySQL queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has over 21,889,464 rows and I'm running **6** of these queries on page load.

```
$woReleased = $database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM (select * from workflow
where action_name = 'Released'
and release_date >= '$startPrevMonth' 
and release_date <= '$endPrevMonth' 
AND project_name = 'tims' group by page_id, headline, release_full_name, release_date
) workflow")->fetchAll();
$c_woReleased = $woReleased[0]["Count"];
```

the problem with this is when I run 6 of these on page load in PHP, it takes aproximately 14 seconds to return the results.

the only difference between the above and the other 5 queries is basically they have different action_name and project_name.

any help to speed this up will be greatly appreciated.

this is the structure of my table.

[image]

Comment: 1. Hello SQL injection. Use prepared statements. 2. Why not cache the results and skip the queries altogether?

Comment: 1. It's an internal app and used by only few people who are not developers or tech geeks
2. I can't cache the results because the results constantly change (every 5 minutes or so).

Comment: 1. Not a valid excuse. 2. Do the numbers need to be absolutely up-to-the-second precise? If no, cache for 5 min or less. If yes, [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: typically you would enable slow-log on the mysql instance to give you hints about the conduct of each query.  At a glance, you dont seem to index field `action_name` which would garantee that each query will require a full table scan. Did i mention enabling slow-logging in MySQL ?  You may also want to select count(`id`) ... or any non-null columnt.

Comment: also, since an image is not worth words, when showing a table structure, i would encourage you to issue `show create table tableName` and paste it as code.

Answer (score 1):

```
select page_id
     , action_name
     , project_name
     , headline
     , release_full_name
     , release_date 
     , count(*) count
  from workflow
 where (action_name, project_name) IN((:action_name,:project_name))
   and release_date >= :startPrevMonth
   and release_date <= :endPrevMonth
 group 
    by action_name
     , project_name
     , page_id
     , headline
     , release_full_name
     , release_date
```

An index on some combination of (action_name, release_date, project_name) would seem sensible (although I'm not certain that MySQL can use an index when IN() is used this way), and, yes, see about prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sammitch's comments - prepared statements are the way to go here and indeed caching but caching appears not to be an option in this case.  Also, by virtue of using SELECT * you are pulling all the data in the table back at once which will slow the query down.  Do you really need to pull every column or can you be more selective?

Using prepared statements will force you anyway to be selective in the columns you pull back.   What also might help you is if you break the request into two:

1.) For the first query just pull back the bare minimum that you need.

2.) if there is a requirement to view a more detailed sample then allow the user to select a record or records which contain all the detail you need.